# Presenting ViewController from Top to Bottom Swift

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, viewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have googling a while for a solution. But didn't get anything what I needed. later I found a Library that works the same but in a reverse manner and the library is this [LNPopupController](https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController)

My Question is how Can I make a viewcontroller move from top to bottom on swipe Gesture ? Can I tweak this library to achieve it ?

Comment: You can certainly tweak it, as it is open source. Feel free to fork it and implement this. It should not be that hard.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to implement a `UIPanGesture` rather than a `UISwipeGesture` based of the project you linked.

### Create a UIPanGestureRecognizer

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewDragged:)];

[yourCustomView addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
```

### Then implement the "viewDragged:" method.

`heightForTheDraggableRegionLeftInTheView` is a value of how much of the view you want to leave on the screen when the user tries to dismiss youCustomView.

```
- (void) viewDragged: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer {
    CGRect viewFrame = gestureRecognizer.view.frame;
    CGPoint locationOfTouch = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

    // Let the user's finger match with the bottom of the NotificationView
    [gestureRecognizer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(viewFrame.origin.x, locationOfTouch.y + draggableHeightOfTheNotificationView - viewFrame.size.height, viewFrame.size.width, viewFrame.size.height)];

    // If the yourCustomView is being dragged too high, make sure you leave a draggable area so that the user can drag it later
    if (locationOfTouch.y  >= self.view.frame.size.height - heightForTheDraggableRegionLeftInTheView) {
    [gestureRecognizer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(viewFrame.origin.x, 0, viewFrame.size.width, viewFrame.size.height)];
    }

    // If the NotificationView will go to far below the screen keep it resting at the bottom of the screen
    if (locationOfTouch.y <= draggableHeightOfTheNotificationView) {
    [gestureRecognizer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(viewFrame.origin.x, draggableHeightOfTheNotificationView * 2 - self.view.frame.size.height, viewFrame.size.width, viewFrame.size.height)];
    }
}
```